# Как сделать блюр по бокам mapView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Привет!

В вью контроллере размещен mapView. Пытаюсь сделать блюр по бокам mapView, т.е. в центре карты нету блюра.

Как можно такое реализовать?

Comment: Пока что пришел к варианту, когда на заднем фоне уже картинка заблюренной карты, а сверху по центру наложен круглый mapView.

Comment: Попробуйте [это][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/ivoleko/ILTranslucentView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый просто способ - положить объекты UIToolbar, системный блюр все сделает за вас